# I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 c# Web App. Project with crystal Reports for Microsoft Visual Studio with service pack 13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 c# Web App. Project with crystal Reports for Microsoft Visual Studio with service pack 13
When I run the application and click show report not response just page refresh

This is the html:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>repsrc

                <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
                </CR:CrystalReportSource>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnViewReport" runat="server" CssClass="myButton" OnClick="btnViewReport_Click" Text="عرض التقرير" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the related Java code:

```
        protected void btnViewReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
            reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/MyReport.rpt"));

            ConnectionInfo connectInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
            {
                ServerName = ".",
                DatabaseName = "MyDataBase",
                UserID = "sa",
                Password = ""
            };

            reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "123");
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tbl in reportdocument.Database.Tables)
            {
                tbl.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectInfo;
                tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tbl.LogOnInfo);
            }
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved after download and setup version 12
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_12.exe
and create a new project using the new version